# Player short audio in UI thread

Tags: android

Is it a good idea to play a short audio within an UI thread? The code is like:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ......

    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.mymp3);
    mMediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Or, I'd better play the audio in an `AsyncTask`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a thumb of rule running that on the main (that's what it actually means in Android) thread is not a good idea.
There are several reasons, for example, what will happen if tomorrow it will not be a short audio sample? how will the application behave if exactly on the same time an incoming call will arrive...it can take 2-3 seconds (depends on the length of the audio sample) until the user will be able to answer.
The "good practice" for audio playing is using [services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

Comment: Thanks for you input. I saw ApiDemos of Android plays audio in main thread, so just want to be lazy to play it in main thread :)

Comment: Well...if the Android developers do that who am I to say otherwise :-) btw: I remember seeing google's presentation for advanced media programming on Android...it said the opposite. It said that you should always keep your application responsive, what you don't have to do on the main thread...don't!

Comment: I see. I will think more about it.